# Unable to check own distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

Good afternoon  I need to estimate different distributions from some data.  Among these distributions, it is necessary to use the Kritsky-Menkel distribution.  I set a formula for the distribution density, indicated some restrictions (it often takes a long time to count with them) and wanted to check it with the help of tests.  For some data, the tests give adequate results and build a beautiful graph.  However, for some other data, it builds a good graph, but the tests show some very high statistics (photo)[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include code as formatted text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: In short @BobHanlon 's answer says that you've only given a special case of the Kritsky-Menkel pdf which happens to be equivalent to a 2-parameter Gamma pdf.  It would seem that either you don't have the right pdf or the Kritsky-Menkel pdf has had this issue since its inception.  A specific reference to that pdf would be helpful.

Comment: Formula № 3 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325997790_Opredelenie_doveritelnyh_intervalov_parametrov_raspredelenia_Krickogo-Menkela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The assumptions for the distribution should include `μ > 0`

```
MuthDistributionDIST[γ_, μ_, b_] := ProbabilityDistribution[
  (Gamma[γ + b]/Gamma[γ])^(γ/b) 
      1/(μ b Gamma[γ]) (x/μ)^(γ/b - 1)
       E^-(Gamma[γ + b]/Gamma[γ] x/μ),
  {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> γ > 0 && b > 0 && μ > 0, 
  Method -> "Normalize"]

pdf = Assuming[γ > 0 && b > 0 && μ > 0, 
  PDF[MuthDistributionDIST[γ, μ, b], x] // Simplify]
```

[image]

This distribution is equivalent to a [`GammaDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaDistribution.html)

```
Assuming[γ > 0 && b > 0 && μ > 0 && x > 0,
 PDF[MuthDistributionDIST[γ, μ, b], x] ==
   PDF[GammaDistribution[γ/b, μ Gamma[γ]/Gamma[γ + b]], x] //
  Simplify]

(* True *)
```

By using three parameters to represent a distribution that is described fully by just two parameters, the three parameters are not unique for any given distribution.

**Edit:** Using the data given in your comment

```
data = {16.1, 15., 15.9, 16.2, 14.3, 15.4, 15.4, 16.6, 15.4, 15.3, 14.9, 15., 
   19.1, 15., 13.2, 18.5, 18.3, 15.6, 16.7, 16.2, 16.4, 16.5, 15.1, 14.1, 
   18.9, 14.6, 17.1, 13.9, 17.1, 12.9, 15.9, 16.2, 18.6, 15.6, 16.9, 18., 
   14.7, 17., 17.8, 16.6, 14.4, 14.1, 18.9, 13.6, 15.1, 18.2, 15.2, 16.5, 
   14.8, 16.9, 16.6, 19.9, 19.2, 14.6, 14.8, 15.6, 17.5, 16.4, 16.1, 18., 
   16.9, 19.4, 19.2, 17.6, 17., 17.9, 16.4, 20.3, 17.3, 14.9};

param = FindDistributionParameters[data, GammaDistribution[a, b]]

(* {a -> 96.615, b -> 0.169347} *)

dist = GammaDistribution[a, b] /. param;
```

Comparing the [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) and [`Variance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html) for the `dist` and `data`

```
Outer[#1[#2] &, {Mean, Variance}, {dist, data}, 1]

(* {{16.3614, 16.3614}, {2.77075, 2.83458}} *)

Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, Min[data], Max[data]}]]
```

[image]

```
DistributionFitTest[data, dist, {"TestDataTable", All}]
```

[image]

Comment: detailed as you do, but in my case, when setting the condition mu, the calculation time increased or mu (average value) took very small values

Comment: E^-((Gamma[γ + b]/Gamma[γ] x/μ)^(1/b))

Comment: Without your data to work with, it is difficult to understand your problem. The mean of your distribution is `Mean[MuthDistributionDIST[γ, μ, b]]`, i.e., `(μ*Gamma[1 +γ])/(b*Gamma[b + γ])` rather than `μ`. If you fit the data with `GammaDistribution[α, β]` then your parameters should be around`Solve[{Mean[GammaDistribution[α, β]] == mean, Variance[GammaDistribution[α, β]] == var}, {α, β}][[1]]`, that is, `{α -> mean^2/var, β -> var/mean}`

Comment: {16.1, 15., 15.9, 16.2, 14.3, 15.4, 15.4, 16.6, 15.4, 15.3, 14.9, 15., 19.1, 15., 13.2, 18.5, 18.3, 15.6, 16.7, 16.2, 16.4, 16.5, 15.1, 14.1, 18.9, 14.6, 17.1, 13.9, 17.1, 12.9, 15.9, 16.2, 18.6, 15.6,16.9, 18., 14.7, 17., 17.8, 16.6, 14.4, 14.1, 18.9, 13.6, 15.1, 18.2, 15.2, 16.5, 14.8, 16.9, 16.6, 19.9, 19.2, 14.6, 14.8, 15.6, 17.5, 16.4, 16.1, 18., 16.9, 19.4, 19.2, 17.6, 17., 17.9, 16.4, 20.3, 17.3, 
14.9}

Comment: Apparently, I'm doing something wrong if the three-parameter gamma distribution I need (the Kritsky-Menkel distribution) does not accept functions. Thanks for the info! Sorry for disturbing you! Good luck